# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' error

Tags: php, composer-php, php-ini

I am trying to execute command "composer install" command. But getting this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: ./ext/intl (The specified module could not be found.), ./ext/php_intl.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: ./ext/intl (The specified module could not be found.), ./ext/php_intl.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: ./ext/intl (The specified module could not be found.), ./ext/php_intl.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: ./ext/intl (The specified module could not be found.), ./ext/php_intl.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
```

this is my php ini file. I removed ";" from " extension=intl" but still it giving me error

```
;extension=bz2
extension=curl
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
;extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

Comment: Have you **installed** that extension? SImply changing the configuration file does not install it. Additionally, this question is not connected to Laravel or Composer - please do not use irrelevant tags, or state the connection if there is one

Comment: @NicoHaase it is present in "ext" folder

Comment: And how did you install it? Please share more details about your setup

Answer (score 5):

Simple copy your icu*63.dll or icu*68.dll (for PHP 8) files from your php directory to apache24/bin

It works for Apache + PHP 8.0.0 x64 + intl

Answer (score 0):

if you use PHP v7.3.2 it has a reported bug in this [link](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77690&edit=1) regarding loading dynamic library intl.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems migrating from php7.4 to php8.1 on a Windows server. The solution was to add the path to php8 directory AND to php8 ext directory in the PATH environnement variable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).